# How do I stop a DIV display outside a table underneath it, using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table & when I click a cell, it displays a DIV(to the right of the mouse) with absolute positioning.

I want the DIV to display using minus co-ords(positioning), so it never display outside the table('#holiday-planner-table') .

Here's the concept I'm thinking of:

```
    if($('#DayInfo'). is outside of $('#holiday-planner-table')) { 

    display $('#DayInfo') with minus co-ordinates 
    } else
{

        $(".WeekDay").click( function(event) {
            $("#DayInfo").css( {position:"absolute", top:event.pageY, left: event.pageX} );

    });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "minus co-ordinates"?

Comment: When i click at the moment ('#DayInfo') always appears to the right if the mouse-click. 

I need to do a check & set the positioning of ('#DayInfo') to
 
top:-X;
left:-X;

Hope this makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a complete solution but you can use $("selector").offset().left or top and $("selector").width() or height to construct two rectangles, check if one is not inside the other and act accordingly.

Comment: I'm a novice at JQuery...I thought if I do some kind of check...then display the DIV using negative positioning this would work?

Please advise

Answer (score 1):

the logic here is to check if the new div coordinates put the div position + size outside the table position + size. if it will, you set the div coordinates back the size of the div. you can do left and top independently.

this should get you pretty close:

```
$(".WeekDay").click(function (e) {

    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;
    var $div = $('#DayInfo');
    var $table = $('#holiday-planner-table');

    if (x + $div.width() > $table.offset().left + $table.width()) {

        x -= $div.width();
    }

    if (y + $div.height() > $table.offset().top + $table.height()) {

        y -= $div.height();
    }

    $div.css({ position: "absolute", top: y, left: x });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking of something among the lines of:

```
if (mousex > (tablew-divw)) divx = mousex-divw
else divx=mousex
```

same thing goes for Y.
Of course, that could mess stuff up if the table actually becomes smaller than the div.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but are you wanting to create some sort of tooltip functionality? If so, have a look at http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html